# Queryset question about base user model Django

Tags: django, primary-key, django-users

Using the Django base User model. I'm getting a duplicate error using the base model pk. Not sure why my app can't seem to figure out which user is posting a comment.

```
def view_api(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_active:
            price, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(
            user=User.objects.filter(pk=user.pk),
            anonymous_user=False,
            comments=request.POST.get('comments')
            )
```

Error:

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/~/query.py" in get_or_create
  538.             return self.get(**kwargs), False

File "/Users/~/query.py" in get
  402.         num = len(clone)

File "/Users/~/query.py" in __len__
  256.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/~/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1242.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/Users/~/query.py" in __iter__
  55.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/Users/~/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1087.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/Users/~/compiler.py" in as_sql
  489.                 where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "/Users/~/compiler.py" in compile
  405.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/Users/~/where.py" in as_sql
  81.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

File "/Users/~/compiler.py" in compile
  405.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/Users/~/related_lookups.py" in as_sql
  130.         return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

File "/Users/~/lookups.py" in as_sql
  163.         rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

File "/Users/~/" in process_rhs
  257.                     'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to '

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/voting/
Exception Value: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Answer (score 2):

A `QuerySet` is a *collection* of objects. But it does not make much sense to pass a collection of `User`s (even though it will contain only one user) to the `user` field.

You do not need to use a `QuerySet` here anyway: you can just use the `request.user` itself, like:

```
def view_api(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_active:
            price, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user
                anonymous_user=False,
                comments=request.POST.get('comments')
            )
    # …
```

Comment: This was my first attempt and it definitely does not work. Get the same error: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: @user10421193: I'm quite convinced that the error is not on this line. It is likely located somewhere else. Can you edit your question with the traceback?

Comment: It's a website modal form. I cannot submit the form due to this error. This is the traceback from the Inspect element. The other error, I keep getting is:Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: . Hence why I tried the other thing.

Comment: @user10421193: but it does not show at what line in the view it generates an error.

Comment: Yes, because this error is coming from the api directly to the Safari browser. This is another error that I get: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<User: joan>]>": "Voting.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: @user10421193: this is likely exactly the error we removed here: since indeed you can not pass a queryset to the `user` parameter. So the same mistake might be multiple times in the view function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199932/discussion-between-user10421193-and-willem-van-onsem).